# render components from array by changing state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, render

New to and learning React. I have a data file that I am reading in in order to render the Card component for each item. Right now, just one card with nothing in it (one card in the initial state) renders. How do I render multiple components by passing through properties from a data file?

**Card.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import data from './../data/data.csv';

class Card extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            text:[],
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        d3.csv(data)
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(data)
                let text = data.forEach((item)=>{
                    console.log(item)
                    return(
                        <div key={item.key}>
                        <h1>{item.quote}</h1>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                this.setState({text:text});
                console.log(this.state.text);
            })
            .catch(function(error){

            })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='card'>
                {this.state.text}
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default Card
```

**index.js**

```js
import Card from './components/Card'

ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
(Found a good explanation here: https://icevanila.com/question/cannot-update-state-in-react-after-using-d3csv-to-load-data)

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;

    d3.csv(data).then(function(data) {
      self.setState({ data: data });
    });

    function callback(data) {
      this.setState({ data: data });
    }

    d3.csv(data).then(callback.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(item => (
          <div className="card" key={item.key}>
            <h1>{item.quote}</h1>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest store the response into a state then render the items with a `map`, something like:

```js
constructor(){
  ...
  this.state = {
    data:[],
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  ...
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      data,
    })
  })
}


render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.data.map(item) => (
        <div className='card' key={item.key}>
          <h1>{item.quote}</h1>
         </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The same problem where the state doesn't seem to actually be updating (state remains in its initial state) seems to be occurring...am I missing something in componentDidMount maybe around binding the new value to  the state..?

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(data)` on your code above?

Comment: [{key: "1", quote: "some text"}, {key: "2", quote: "more text"}...]

Comment: checkout the codesanbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/young-hooks-0w3q3 and it renders properly

Comment: any idea how to get around the "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" when doing componentDidMount() {
   d3.csv(data)
   .then(function(data){
     this.setState({
      data: data
     });
   })
  }
?

Comment: I didn't know that you caught an error.. so basically, you need to bind `this` to your function.. or an easier way is to use arrow function `() => {}` which automatically binds `this`.. I've updated the answer above.